# Jest: Is there a way to test a Redux reducer that uses a conditional initialState?

Tags: javascript, testing, redux, jestjs

I am testing a Redux reducer with Jest.

The `initialState` is conditional (uses ternary operators to decide properties.) Since the reducer doesn't have access to `window` in the test scope, it can only default to the ternary's falsy result. This is causing my coverage report to fail.

There are two things I'm trying to do here:

1. Call the reducer inside a scope that has access to `window`.
2. Create a new `initialState` inside that scope and set the values based off of `window`.

I've tried `.bind()`,  Jest's `jest.fn()` to mock it, but wasn't able to get anything to work. Then I realized it might not be possible to call initialState since it is defined outside of the reducer export. Maybe a `require()` in the right place could instantiate a different version, and that could be done under a new scope with `window` in it?

```
// reducer.js
import constants from '../constants'

const initialState = {
  user: window.user || '',
  token: window.user ? window.user.token : '',
  notification: '',
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.FETCH_USER:
      return state.user

     default:
      return state
  }
}
```

```
// reducer.test.js
import reducer from './reducer'

const initialState = {
  user: '',
  token: '',
  notification: '',
}

describe('reducer', () => {
  it('should return the initial state', () => {

    // uses initialState without window in scope
    expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual(
      initialState
    )

    const global = {
      window: {
        user: {
          token: 'tag-AAA',
          permissions: true,
        },
      },
    }

    // needs access to window
    expect(reducer.bind(global)(undefined, {})).toEqual(
      {
        user: {
          token: 'tag-AAA',
          permissions: true,
        },
        token: 'tag-AAA',
        notification: '',
      }
    )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsdom` test environment is enabled by default in current Jest version and already declares `window`, `global.window === window`. This is the reason why test suite doesn't fail on import, otherwise `window.user` would cause an error.

reducer.js is evaluated on import so it cannot be affected by `window` in the test. It should be re-imported after mocking `window`. `window` mock should be reset after the test to avoid test cross-contamination.

It can be:

```
const reducer = require('./reducer').default

expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual(initialState)

jest.resetModules()

jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get').mockReturnValue({ user: {...} })

const reducer = require('./reducer').default

expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual(...)

...

afterEach(() => {
  jest.restoreAllMocks() // or restoreMocks config option
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that when you import the reducer, the `initialState` is set.

This causes that it is not possible to change the values of the window parameters before executing your different test scenarios. This is, you can not do a test to check when you have something in `window.user` and another to check when `window.user` is undefined.

In order to be able to do that, you will have to change the way you define the initial state in the reducer. One way to do so, is to create a method that returns the initial state:

```
// reducer.js
import constants from '../constants'

const getInitialState = () => ({
    user: window.user || '',
    token: window.user ? window.user.token : '',
    notification: '',
});

export default (state = getInitialState(), action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.FETCH_USER:
      return state.user

     default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now you can test both scenarios:

```
describe('reducer', () => {
    it('should return the initial state', () => {
        expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual({
            user: '',
            token: '',
            notification: '',
        });
    });

    it('should return the initial state from window', () => {
        global.user = {
            token: 'tag-AAA',
            permissions: true,
        };

        expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual({
            user: { token: 'tag-AAA', permissions: true, },
            token: 'tag-AAA',
            notification: '',
        });

        // Set the global value to undefined so that it does not affect following tests.
        global.user = undefined;
    });
});
```